# Probability of one, or both happening

Tags: probability

You have two flowers, a yellow one and a red one. The probability that each one is pollinated during its two week blooming period is $0.8$. The probability that the red one is pollinated given that the yellow one is pollinated is $0.9$.

I'm having a bit of trouble with this question:

What is the probability that one or the other or both is pollinated? Give your answer to $2$ digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given information:

$$P(R) = P(Y) = 0.8$$

$$P(R|Y) = 0.9$$

Relevant formulae:

$$P(R|Y) = \frac{P(R \cap Y)}{P(Y)}$$

$$P(R \cup Y) = P(R) + P(Y) - P(R \cap Y)$$

Can you complete it from here?

Comment: Thanks! So it should be 0.8 + 0.8 - 0.72 = 0.88 ?

Comment: That looks right to me.